# Ruby on Rails: Trying to understand Undefined method, nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error

I'm trying to understand how I'm getting two different outputs from rails

If I have this:

```
<%= if value.user.present?
  link_to value.user.email, value.user 
end %>
```

I gives me what I wanted. It out puts the email of the user with its link associated with it.
But when I take the `if` statement out,

```
<%= link_to value.user.email, value.user %>
```

I get this error.

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't get it? Aren't I just doing the same thing with the first statement? It outputs the link_to.

Why am I get two different outputs with what I thought was the same statement?

Comment: Are you doing this inside a loop?

Comment: @santhosh I am doing it in a loop

Comment: That is the reason. For at least one of the values, user is nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's happening because you called a method on nil (value.user is nil)

An easy way to shorten it up...

```
<%= link_to(value.user.email, value.user) if value.user %>
```

A note, `if value.user` could be nil (not false), but is still considered 'falsey' in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

in your if condition it checks whether your user is present and if present it will give the proper output... but somehow if your user is not present it will check like for nil and generates that error, to avoid that you have to write the condition or rescue nil on that line...

Answer (score 0):

This error would pop up if any of your value.user items do not have an email associated.

I've encountered this when migrating and not all rows have the item assigned.